# Difference between call syntax in solidity

Tags: solidity

Is there a difference between this line:

```
(bool success, ) = dest.call{value: 0.1 ether}("");
```

and this one:

```
(bool success, ) = dest.call.value(0.1 ether)("");
```

Which one should i use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior solc 0.6.4: `(bool success, ) = dest.call.value(0.1 ether)("");`.

As of solc 0.6.4: `(bool success, ) = dest.call{value: 0.1 ether}("");`.